# Why does this bash fork bomb not work on my RHEL VM?

Tags: bash, rhel, virtual-machine, vmware, fork

I'm running a RHEL 6.5 VM in a VMware ESXi environment and accessing it through the vSphere Web Client virtual console (in my browser).

I wanted to crash this machine on purpose and executed

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

However, all I get is

```
bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

a couple of times and then it stops from doing anything. I can easily exit via Ctrl+C and continue working normally.
What could be the reason this fork bomb does not work?

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Extreme lags leading to an unresponsive system, where the only option to go back to normal is to reboot.

Comment: what is the limit on the number of processes that user can run? (`ulimit -u`)

Comment: Output is 62788

Comment: RHEL 6: max user processes is set to 1024 for root and non root.

Answer (score 2):

More modern OSes protect themselves from this sort of misuse by default, usually by setting user limits. That's probably why the system is still responsive - it only lets you allocate memory up to a certain amount, which is much less than the machine has available.

Comment: What kind of limit would that most likely be? Note that I'm acting as root there.

Comment: Look in `/etc/security/limits.conf` - I would guess it's some sort of process (`nproc`) or memory limit. Just because you're running as root doesn't mean the system isn't trying to protect itself against you fork-bombing it.

Comment: That file is entirely commented out, so it seems the limit is enforced somewhere else.